# Azure Static Web App with Managed Functions cannot find module

Tags: azure, azure-devops, deployment, azure-functions, azure-static-web-app

I have a monorepo that contains 5 packages in total:

- frontend
- backend
- library 1
- library 2
- library 3

The backend uses the libraries. Whenever I emulate the SWA everything works fine but whenever I deploy the application, I get the error:

```
Exception while executing function: Functions.npm-dependency-report Result: Failure
Exception: Worker was unable to load function npm-dependency-report: 'Cannot find module 'rimraf'
Require stack:
- /home/site/wwwroot/dist/npm-dependency-report/index.js
- /azure-functions-host/workers/node/dist/src/worker-bundle.js
- /azure-functions-host/workers/node/dist/src/nodejsWorker.js'
Stack: Error: Cannot find module 'rimraf'
Require stack:
- /home/site/wwwroot/dist/npm-dependency-report/index.js
- /azure-functions-host/workers/node/dist/src/worker-bundle.js
- /azure-functions-host/workers/node/dist/src/nodejsWorker.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
    at Object.apply (/azure-functions-host/workers/node/dist/src/worker-bundle.js:2:38624)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at /home/site/wwwroot/dist/npm-dependency-report/index.js:279:5348
    at /home/site/wwwroot/dist/npm-dependency-report/index.js:1:222
    at /home/site/wwwroot/dist/npm-dependency-report/index.js:279:12306
    at /home/site/wwwroot/dist/npm-dependency-report/index.js:1:222
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/site/wwwroot/dist/npm-dependency-report/index.js:283:1294)
```

The module rimraf is installed and included in the package.json of the backend. Whenever I remove the line that uses rimraf, it gives the same error with another dependency called 'node-gyp', which is not even a dependency of my project, but a dependency of one of my dependencies.

I deployed the application using [Azure SWA CLI](https://azure.github.io/static-web-apps-cli/), and whatever I do, I cannot get rid of the error.

Command used to emulate the SWA: `swa start --app-location ./packages/frontend --api-location ./packages/backend  --output-location ./dist`

Command used to deploy the SWA: `swa deploy --app-location ./packages/frontend --api-location ./packages/backend --output-location ./dist`

Comment: Were you able to solve this?

Comment: @Aijaz I think bundling the package which had the error fixed the issue. I used esbuild to bundle all the dependencies of my backend (the one that throwed the 'Cannot find module') in to one js file. Deploying this js file fixed the issue

Comment: So I think thi is caused by library1..3 not being inside backend (inside --api-location folder). I think that SWA will only publish content of --app-location+--output-location and --api-location. In your case SWA publishes all content of folder ./packages/frontend/dist and ./packages/backend. This means that ./packages/library1..3 folders are NEVER published to azure and thus require statement fails as they are NOT there.